# Canada B-1 Visitor-Business Visa for tourism?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, canada

I have a valid multiple entry Canada visa from a business trip a couple of years ago. I’m planning to travel to Canada this year to visit family/ as a tourist. Can I use the same visa??

Tried searching the ircc site and found this, though it just have different wording.

https://www.cic.gc.ca/english/helpcentre/answer.asp?qnum=456&top=16

Comment: In answer to a question identical to yours, the cited government of Canada page says "If it is a multiple-entry visa and it has not expired, you can use it to enter Canada for both business and tourism." Is this unclear?

Comment: Thank you. It somehow does, though the site just mentioned “temporary resident visa” and not specifially “visitor-business visa” so just worried that the immigration in the border could say this

Comment: There is only one short term visa in Canada, called the "temporary resident visa". It's valid for tourism, business, family visits, short term study, and (with appropriate permits) long term study. Everything that is commonly called a "tourist visa" or "business visa" is really a TRV.